# SQLite: How to select 10 values for each item

Tags: python, sqlite, data-science, data-analysis

**I'm trying to select only 10 values in ASC order for each symbol in my list.** Currently I have a query that will select all values :

```
#syms list will change every time new data is ingested and processed... So I have it static here for reference...   
syms = "'O:SPY230118P00392000','O:SPY230118C00398000'"

query = """SELECT * FROM data WHERE (sym IN ({})) ORDER BY t ASC;""".format(syms)

df = pd.read_sql(query, connectionDB)
```

I want to achieve a DataFrame with the output of index 0 to 9 having "O:SPY230118C00398000" and then 10 to 20 having "O:SPY230118P00392000." The index does not matter, but I only want 10 data points of one symbol and 10 data points of the other symbol. This is what I get with the query above. I only copied the output till 20.

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE (sym IN ('O:SPY230118P00392000','O:SPY230118C00398000')) ORDER BY t ASC;
                      sym    x     p    s                                 t           q
0    O:SPY230118P00392000  304  0.12    8  2023-01-18 12:08:38.447000-05:00  1139986131
1    O:SPY230118P00392000  300  0.11    1  2023-01-18 12:09:53.323000-05:00  1145850103
2    O:SPY230118P00392000  304  0.10    1  2023-01-18 12:09:54.161000-05:00  1145899875
3    O:SPY230118P00392000  323  0.11   10  2023-01-18 12:09:57.050000-05:00  1146018132
4    O:SPY230118P00392000  312  0.10    2  2023-01-18 12:10:03.822000-05:00  1146438576
5    O:SPY230118C00398000  313  0.07    5  2023-01-18 12:10:06.105000-05:00   902343835
6    O:SPY230118C00398000  312  0.07    1  2023-01-18 12:10:06.105000-05:00   902343837
7    O:SPY230118C00398000  304  0.07   16  2023-01-18 12:10:06.105000-05:00   902343841
8    O:SPY230118C00398000  304  0.07   11  2023-01-18 12:10:06.105000-05:00   902343842
9    O:SPY230118C00398000  304  0.07    9  2023-01-18 12:10:06.105000-05:00   902343843
10   O:SPY230118C00398000  304  0.07    6  2023-01-18 12:10:06.105000-05:00   902343844
11   O:SPY230118C00398000  303  0.07    1  2023-01-18 12:10:06.105000-05:00   902343846
12   O:SPY230118C00398000  301  0.07   50  2023-01-18 12:10:06.122000-05:00   902344187
13   O:SPY230118C00398000  301  0.07    1  2023-01-18 12:10:06.122000-05:00   902344188
14   O:SPY230118C00398000  304  0.07    1  2023-01-18 12:10:07.988000-05:00   902404488
15   O:SPY230118C00398000  304  0.07    5  2023-01-18 12:10:08.149000-05:00   902412599
16   O:SPY230118C00398000  301  0.07   45  2023-01-18 12:10:08.165000-05:00   902414573
17   O:SPY230118C00398000  300  0.07    1  2023-01-18 12:10:10.065000-05:00   902506865
18   O:SPY230118P00392000  304  0.12    1  2023-01-18 12:10:15.275000-05:00  1147434567
19   O:SPY230118C00398000  304  0.06    1  2023-01-18 12:14:17.089000-05:00   917394276
20   O:SPY230118P00392000  319  0.11    4  2023-01-18 12:15:58.461000-05:00  1176206005
```

I am using SQLite3, but I am not sure how to craft the query. I know that I need to use LIMIT, however, this only selects 10 items total rather than 10 of each symbol.

10 of each symbol refers to selecting only 10 values from "O:SPY230118P00392000" and then 10 values from "O:SPY230118C00398000." The indexing does not matter since I can apply a groupby.get_group(symbol) later.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i75164067/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what is specifically "10 of each symbol"?

Answer (score 0):

However not sure fully understand the question.

pandas way

```
df.groupby('syms').head(10)
```

SQL way

```
SELECT * FROM (select id,sym, row_number() over (partition by `sym` order by id desc) as counters from data ) as t Where counters < 10;
```